# Minimum number of cycles in a connected graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Please answer
Want proof

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices. Prove that the minimum number of cycles in $G$ is $m-n-1$. (Where one cycle is a path that starts that begins and ends at the same vertex.)

Comment: Hint: Deleting an edge from a cycle in a connected graph will not disconnect the graph (why?). 2nd hint: What do you know about connected, acyclic graphs on $n$ vertices? See if you can figure out how to use these hints.

Comment: Note that a [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph), which just consists of one cycle, has $m=n$.